# Как загрузить к себе на жёсткий диск файл который пользователь отправил на сервер php?

Tags: php, файлы, ssd

У меня есть два файла php. На index.php вы загружаете файл и отправляете его на index2.php. Как на index2.php реализовать сохранение файла к себе на жёсткий диск?
index.php:

```
'''

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="index2.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type="file" name="filename" id="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
'''
```

index2.php:

```
'''
<?php
echo $_FILES['filename']['name'];
?>
'''
```

Comment: вы в поисковике не нашли ни одну статью на эту тему?

Comment: Там только про то, как загрузить файл на сервер, а не на жёсткий диск

Comment: Простите, а на сервер он куда загружается (где хранится)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rename("path_from", "path_ro");
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]